# how to define constraints for SFINAE and static assert in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, static-assert

I am experimenting on serialization/deserialization with template, and have now something working. 
Obviously, when implementing it, I ran into many troubles with hundreds of compiler error logs. 
Before extending my library further, I would like to secure it a bit, using SFINAE (which I only used scarcely so far) and static_asserts.

Not to mess up any further with my lib, I'm training in a sandbox :

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9eb4eaefaac90fc0

I want to define a few predicates :

- is_a_base to check the object derives from Base.
- is_insertable & is_extractable to check if operator>> and operator<< have been defined for this type.

I want to be able to use those predicates for both SFINAE specialization and static_assert.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

//forward declaration
class Base;

//"Template typedef" to check predicates
template <typename T>
using is_a_Base = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, void>::type;

template <typename T, typename is = std::istream>
using is_extractable = decltype (is{} >> T{});

template <typename T, typename os = std::ostream>
using is_insertable = decltype (os{} << T{});

//Test classes
class Base{
    public:
        std::string getStr(){ return "Base.getStr()";}
};
class Derived: public Base {};

class Other{};

//A template class with its specializations with SFINAE
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class C{
    public:
        static void f(T& o){
            std::cout << "f<T> default !" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class C<T, is_a_Base<T>>
{
    public:
        static void f (T& o)
        {
            std::cout << "f<is_a_A>() ! " << o.getStr() << std::endl;
        }
};

template<typename T>
class C<T, is_insertable<T> >
{
    public:
        static void f (T& o)
        {
            std::cout << "f<is_insertable() ! " << o << std::endl;
        }
};


template<typename T>
std::string g(T& ref)
{
    //static_assert(is_a_Base<T>, "T is not a Base"); //can't figure out the syntax here
    return ref.getStr();
}



int main(){
    Base a;
    Derived b;
    int myint = 1;
    std::string str="toto";

    Other oops;


    C<Base>::f(a);
    C<Derived>::f(b);
    C<int>::f(myint);      //Not calling is_insertable ??
    C<std::string>::f(str); //Not calling is_insertable ??
    C<Other>::f(oops);

    std::cout << "g:" << g(a) << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "g:" << g(oops) << std::endl; //should be blasted by the static assert
}
```

Results :

```
f<is_a_A>() ! Base.getStr()
f<is_a_A>() ! Base.getStr()
f<T> default !
f<T> default !
f<T> default !
g:Base.getStr()
```

So far, is_a_base is working for SFINAE.
However, is_insertable is not working for the int and string variables ?
Also I could not figure out how to properly reuse the is_a_base predicate into my assert statement.

(Since I am constrained with a cross-compiler not supporting beyond C++11, I can't use benefits from C++14 and beyond.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using SFINAE to select a specialization of `C` through the default argument `void`. This means that the specialization's signature must substitute correctly, but *also* produce `void` for the specialization to be selected. As it stands, your stream traits:

```
template <typename T, typename is = std::istream>
using is_extractable = decltype (is{} >> T{});

template <typename T, typename os = std::ostream>
using is_insertable = decltype (os{} << T{});
```

... actually produce the return type from `operator >>` (resp. `<<`), typically  an `is &` (resp. `os &`). Your naming is a bit confusing as well since `is_...` implies a boolean value, which they are not. Hence my suggested fix:

template

```
using enable_if_base = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type;
//                                              `void` is the default already ^

template <typename T, typename is = std::istream>
using enable_if_extractable = decltype (std::declval<is &>() >> std::declval<T &>(), void());
//                                                                                 ^^^^^^^^

template <typename T, typename os = std::ostream>
using enable_if_insertable = decltype (std::declval<os &>() << std::declval<T const &>(), void());
//                                                                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Note that I also replaced `T{}` with appropriately-qualified `std::declval`s, since you cannot assume that the relevant types are actually default-constructible — in fact, `std::istream` and `std::ostream` are not.

Comment: OK, thanks ! I thought that the default void parameter was then a placeholder and the returned type of the function wasn't important. And how would it suit best to reuse those traits into a static_assert ?

Comment: @Pellekrino see the [detection idiom](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/detection-idiom/). Essentially it wraps the SFINAE-check and returns whether it succeded.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. `std::ostream` and `std::istream` do not have default constructors so creating them the way you did caused a substitution failure and so the primary template was used as the fallback. Use `declval<T&>` in order to avoid creating a temporary with the default constructor.
2. The second template argument in the primary template must be `void` in order for it to be selected. As you have it, it returns the type of the result of `[i/o]s{} << T{}` (sic) which will be `std::ostream&`, and `std::istream&` for the other. You can fix this up by wrapping the second argument in a `std::void_t`.

#1

```
template <typename T, typename is = std::istream>
using is_extractable = decltype (std::declval<is&>() >> T{});

template <typename T, typename os = std::ostream>
using is_insertable = decltype (std::declval<os&>() << T{});
```

#2

```
template<typename T>
class C<T, std::void_t<is_a_Base<T>>>

template<typename T>
class C<T, std::void_t<is_insertable<T>>>
```

Comment: Thanks ;) void_t is c++17, although it could be rewritten for c++11) how would it suit best to reuse those traits into a static_assert ? (same question than my other answer's comment)

Comment: @Pellekrino Well, as written, `is_a_Base` and `is_insertable` are not suitable to be used in a boolean context, since they don't return anything convertible to bool. Since their names are asking the question "is this a base class of...?" and "is this insertable" they should be rewritten to return true or false based on these questions. For example, you can change `is_a_Base` to `using is_a_Base = std::is_base_of<Base, T>`, change the partial specializations to `C<T, std::enable_if_t<is_a_Base<T>{}>>`, then in the `static_assert` you can do `static_assert(is_a_Base<T>{}, "T is not a Base")`